# Netbeans Java GUI calculator - How to perform calculations for more than 2 numbers?

Tags: java, parsing, netbeans, calculator

I've made a java calculator in netbeans which performs simple, +-*/ operations to TWO numbers. Code below:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Calculation extends javax.swing.JFrame {

double firstNum;
double secondNum;
double thirdNum;
double result;
String operation;
String operation2;

/**
 * Creates new form Calculation
 */
public Calculation() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">  

private void initComponents() {
     // Generated code here for GUI Components....             

  // Below is my calculations and displays...
private void Btn4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

   String takein;
   takein = txtDisplay.getText() + Btn4.getText();
   txtDisplay.setText(takein);        
}                                    

private void Btn1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

   String takein;
   takein = txtDisplay.getText() + Btn1.getText();
   txtDisplay.setText(takein);
}                                    

private void Btn2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

   String takein;
   takein = txtDisplay.getText() + Btn2.getText();
   txtDisplay.setText(takein);
}                                    

private void Btn3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

   String takein;
   takein = txtDisplay.getText() + Btn3.getText();
   txtDisplay.setText(takein);
}                                    

private void Btn5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

   String takein;
   takein = txtDisplay.getText() + Btn5.getText();
   txtDisplay.setText(takein);
}                                    

private void Btn6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

   String takein;
   takein = txtDisplay.getText() + Btn6.getText();
   txtDisplay.setText(takein);       
}                                    

private void Btn7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

   String takein;
   takein = txtDisplay.getText() + Btn7.getText();
   txtDisplay.setText(takein);        
}                                    

private void Btn8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

   String takein;
   takein = txtDisplay.getText() + Btn8.getText();
   txtDisplay.setText(takein);      
}                                    

private void Btn9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

   String takein;
   takein = txtDisplay.getText() + Btn9.getText();
   txtDisplay.setText(takein);       
}                                    

private void Btn0ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

   String takein;
   takein = txtDisplay.getText() + Btn0.getText();
   txtDisplay.setText(takein);
}                                    

private void BtnPointActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

   String takein;
   takein = txtDisplay.getText() + BtnPoint.getText();
   txtDisplay.setText(takein);
}                                        

private void BtnCancelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

   txtDisplay.setText("");        
}                                         

private void BtnPlusActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    firstNum = Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText());
    txtDisplay.setText("+");
    operation = "+";
}                                       

private void BtnMinusActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    firstNum = Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText());
    txtDisplay.setText("-");
    operation = "-";     
}                                        

private void BtnMultiplyActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    firstNum = Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText());
    txtDisplay.setText("*");
    operation = "*";
}                                           

private void BtnDivideActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    firstNum = Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText());
    txtDisplay.setText("/");
    operation = "/";      
}                                         

private void BtnPlusMinusActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

    double operan = (Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(txtDisplay.getText())));
    operan = operan * (-1);
    txtDisplay.setText(String.valueOf(operan));
}                                            

private void BtnEqualsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    String answer;
    secondNum = Double.parseDouble(txtDisplay.getText());
    switch (operation)
    {
        case "+":
            result = firstNum + secondNum;
            answer = String.format("%.0f", result);
            txtDisplay.setText(answer);

            break;

        case "-":
            result = firstNum - secondNum;
            answer = String.format("%.0f", result);
            txtDisplay.setText(answer);

            break;

        case "*":
            result = firstNum * secondNum;
            answer = String.format("%.0f", result);
            txtDisplay.setText(answer);

            break;

        case "/":
            result = firstNum / secondNum;
            answer = String.format("%.0f", result);
            txtDisplay.setText(answer);
    }
}                                         

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    // Generated code here.. for GUI.. not really relevant.
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify  // Auto generated via designview                   
private javax.swing.JButton Btn0;
private javax.swing.JButton Btn1;
private javax.swing.JButton Btn2;
private javax.swing.JButton Btn3;
private javax.swing.JButton Btn4;
private javax.swing.JButton Btn5;
private javax.swing.JButton Btn6;
private javax.swing.JButton Btn7;
private javax.swing.JButton Btn8;
private javax.swing.JButton Btn9;
private javax.swing.JButton BtnCancel;
private javax.swing.JButton BtnDivide;
private javax.swing.JButton BtnEquals;
private javax.swing.JButton BtnMinus;
private javax.swing.JButton BtnMultiply;
private javax.swing.JButton BtnPlus;
private javax.swing.JButton BtnPlusMinus;
private javax.swing.JButton BtnPoint;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtDisplay;
// End of variables declaration                   
 }
```

So as you can see from my code it is only allowing 2 number input. So if I was to input 2+2+2, the answer would still be 4. Could anyone point me into the right direction as to how I could allow a 3rd, 4th, 5th number etc to be added for calculations?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do is when user press 2 , + , 2 and then if user again press +/- perform action for 2+2=4 and now pretend as 4+/-x ...

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of doing that, is there any chance you could point me in the right direction though as to how I could implement this?

Comment: Call the Bthequalaction every time user press +/-/* . In btnequalaciton check if second number is null don't do anything. If there is second number perform the action and set the answer as first number and make second number null.

Comment: If your problem is solved with solution i have gave you. Please select it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to calculate the expression all at once upon pressing the '=' button, I would suggest using a [Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) like structure(java.util.Stack) for evaluating an infix operation as follows:

1. Keep one stack for operators(+-/*) and one for operands(1,2,3...).
2. Mentally assign a priority to your operators(for example, '+' and '-' at low priority and '*' and '/' at high).
3. Once the '=' button is clicked, go to step 4.
4. check if the next token from the input is an operand or an operator and push it into the appropriate stack.
5. Repeat step 4 until a high priority operator('*' or '/') is pushed into the operator stack, then go to step 6. If input finishes before a high priority operator is pushed into the stack, go to step 7.
6. Retrieve the token after the operator and pop the operand and operator stacks. Then apply the operator to the two operands and push the result back into the operand stack. Go to step 5.
7. Since no high priority operators are left and all the input is in its respective stack, pop two operands and an operator from their respective stacks and apply the operator to the operands. Push the result back into the operands. Repeat until only 1 operand is left. That is the result.

The logic behind operator priorities is that normally the multiplication and division happens before addition and subtraction of course.

For a much more rigorous and general solution to the problem of evaluating expressions please refer to the [Shunting Yard Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). The above version is a very much simplified form of the same(I believe).